# Wireless driver not working for WPA after update to 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10

I updated from 12.04(All working) to 12.10 last night and unable to get the wireless driver working properly. It seems to work with no wireless security, but not with WPA.  I have tried with other wireless devices and all seems ok.

The laptop is a ASUS X53Z.  When I run the following

```
lspci -nn
```

I get the following output

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
```

Hope someone can please help???

Answer (score 2):

Edit the file

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add this

```
blacklist acer-wmi
```

or you might have to do the following:

```
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

---

If that works you can make it permanent:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Add the following line:

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

Reboot.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for answering my question.  I can dynamically remove and add the driver using and the following and that works.  Although I dont have the /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf file.  What file should I change?

Comment: Just created the file, added the line above and rebooted.  All works fine.  Thanks cprofit

Comment: glad to know it worked @paul - you should accept the answer so this is marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

even with [cprofitt's](https://askubuntu.com/a/218513/65926) answer this wasn't solved for me.

My config is HP 450 with ath9k driver.

For me `lspci -nn` yields same as the OP.

I found from this [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12371714&postcount=5) that it will be solved if the N-channel (802.11n) is disabled in the router.

Although it may not be feasible to somebody, this is an alternate answer (which is definitely working for me).