# Internet does not work on Windows 8 pre-installed laptop

Tags: wireless, internet-connection, windows-8, dns

I'm booting into ubuntu using a LiveUSB on my Windows 8 Sony Vaio laptop. It connects to the wi-fi but nothing works. I checked the proxy settings on the browser. Even when I try to ping google.com from the terminal, nothing happens. It seems like there's no DNS resolution happening.
Is this something to do with the Windows UEFI secure boot?

I've installed ubuntu on a number of windows vista and 7 laptops before and have never had this problem.

Any help on this is appreciated.

---

Relevant `lspci -nnk` entry:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e044]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
        Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Using `ping`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please include *specific* information about your hardware. Include the output of `lsusb` and `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(wireless|network)"`. An no, if Ubuntu boots, it has nothing to do with UEFI vs BIOS anymore.

Comment: what happens if you try pinging your wifi router (usually 192.168.1.1 or similar)?

Comment: @gertvdijk http://pastebin.com/BNiF6Ndi

Comment: @Ayush Please **edit** your question to include relevant information. It's how this site works. I'll do it for you this time.

Comment: Please try the instructions from [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/218513/88802) from a question with the exact same hardware. If that works, then we can mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: @gertvdijk It works now, but the internet is too slow. Like dial-up slow. It takes 2 minutes to load the google.com homepage. Same with other websites. Also, eveything is working fine on windows, so nothing wrong with the internet connection.

Comment: @Ayush Well, the answer I posted is supposed to address that very issue. I'm lost now. It's hard to provide support like this - as we don't have the same hardware. One clue from a corner on the interwebs: disable 802.11n on your access point (only enable 802.11b/g). By the way, you *did* apply all system updates, and you *are* on a recent Ubuntu release (12.04/12.10), right?